# Possible to give Finder back focus after opening and closing file (e.g. in editor)?

Tags: finder

When you open a file with finder (by pressing cmd-o) and subsequently close the file in whatever application opened it (e.g. TextEdit for a .txt file) by pressing for example cmd-w, the application still has the focus.

Is it possible to always have the Finder get the focus back (like on Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to get OS X to behave like Windows in this case, but if the document you open is the only window open in that application, you can quit the app with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> instead of just closing the window. If you need to keep the app open after closing the window, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to quickly return to the Finder once you close the window.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @joelseph's suggestion of completing editing with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> rather than <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, if your goal is to preview a file (as opposed to editing it) and the go back to browsing other files, using QuickLook (requires OS X 10.5.0 and later), invoked by pressing the space bar, will allow you to read a file, then return to browsing when you are done reading the file. This doesn't help if you need to *edit* the file.